# Why does `require 'native'` throw an exception in opalrb?

Tags: opalrb

I'm taking baby steps with `opalrb`, here is my `main.rb`:

```ruby
require 'native'

def main
    puts "hi from the main function in main.rb"
end

def demoButton
    outputDiv = Element.find('output').get(0)
    puts outputDiv.methods.sort
end
```

It's included within `<head>` after `opal.js` and `...opal-parser.js" onload="Opal.load('opal-parser')"` but the console shows an exception thrown:

```js
{
  message: "cannot load such file -- native",
​  name: "LoadError",
​  stack: ""
}
```

`native` seems to be part of the opal standard library, so why is there a problem including it?

Comment: Here's the demo (may be fixed when you read this): https://vsharapov.github.io/opalrb-boilerplate/main.html
And the code: https://github.com/VSharapov/opalrb-boilerplate/tree/96d80b3d17df52c7ef14f7429dd87fc77a3a3ead

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.opalrb.com/opal/current/native.js"></script>
```

The stdlib part (like native) of Opal isn't included in `opal.js`. For a full list of stdlib, take a look here:

https://cdn.opalrb.com/opal/current/index.html